# how to stop a progress bar control from well progressing

Tags: winforms

I have a marquee style progress bar
at some point I want it to stop well marqueeing I guess
How do I ?
this is on win7 .NET 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [`Style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.style.aspx) property to a value other than `Marquee`:

```
progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee; // marquee animation starts
progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous; // marquee animation stops
```